# Reshaping wide-format data into frequencies

Tags: r, reshape

I have data on deaths by country, hemisphere that the country is in (Northern, Southern, Equatorial), and season (Summer, Fall, Winter, Spring). Of course, any given country always falls in the same hemisphere. Currently the data are in wide format (each row corresponds to a different case).

I am trying to reshape the dataset for Poisson regression, so I need four rows for each country (one for each season) and a frequency variable representing the number of cases occurring in that season in that country. I also need to keep the hemisphere variable.

Here’s what I tried:

```
 #three countries (A, B, C)
 country = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 20), rep("C", 4))

 #A is Northern, B and C are Equatorial
 hemisphere = c(rep("Northern", 5), rep("Equatorial", 20), rep("Equatorial", 4))

 #season of each occurrence
 season = sample(c("Fall", "Winter", "Summer", "Spring"), size=29, replace=T)

 fake = data.frame(country, hemisphere, season)

 #almost works
 fake2 = as.data.frame(table(fake$country, fake$season, fake$hemisphere))
```

The problem with the result is that we get rows with Freq=0 corresponding to conditions like country A, Equatorial because that is an impossible condition. In other words, there should not be rows corresponding to country-hemisphere combinations that do not exist. How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just remove the offending rows? `fake2 = fake2[fake2$Freq > 0, ]`

Comment: Furthermore, if you use Poisson regression the constructed model.matrix will create zeros even though you do have them in your data. So you may be expending needless effort.

Comment: @Peyton, that wouldn't work because in my real data set, sometimes the frequency really is zero (even in possible combinations of country and hemisphere).

Comment: @DWin, I don't think I understand what you mean about the design matrix?

Comment: It's what the `glm` function creates with the arguments on the RHS of a regression formula.

Comment: @half-pass: If country will uniquely determine hemisphere, then the dependency will be identified and the hemisphere coefficient will be set to NA.

Comment: @DWin, Ah, thank you. In that case, I will use the solution I already have.

Comment: Edit: Actually, I would still be interested in a solution to the problem since mine is causing problems when doing descriptive stats.

Comment: What's wrong with Peyton's?

Comment: @DWin, I responded above -- my real dataset is a little more complicated than the toy one.